# Setting this context to a callback function with call

Tags: javascript, ember.js, call, bind

I'm trying to understand a way to assign this context to a promise without using bind.

If I have the following promise

```
Ember.RSVP.Promise.all([
    //THIS REFERS TO AN EMBER OBJECT
    this.store.find('product', this.productSpecifications(null,null,"TRP")),
    this.store.find('product', this.productSpecifications(null,null,"TRF")),
]).then(function (values){
    this.set('recommendedPaid', values[0]);
    this.set('recommendedFree', values[1]);
}.call(this)).catch(function(err){
    console.log('error found in recommended products');
});
```

When I do call(this) to the callback function, I can access the js object but the response "values" are lost.

How can set context to Ember Object with this and pass the promise response

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in the classical way, by saving a reference to the `this` you are interested in:

```
var self = this;

Ember.RSVP.Promise.all([
    self.store.find('product', self.productSpecifications(null,null,"TRP")),
    self.store.find('product', self.productSpecifications(null,null,"TRF")),
]).then(function (values){
    self.set('recommendedPaid', values[0]);
    self.set('recommendedFree', values[1]);
}.catch(function(err){
    console.log('error found in recommended products');
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to check a way out of saving the current scope in a variable, and go with the scope current flow

Comment: So you're trying to avoid `var self = this;`? Why?

Comment: Just to see if I can use the js scope flow, without using bind(this)

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. `bind(this)` and `var self = this;` is one and the same thing, in the end: Make explicit any object references you want to use and get on with your life. Ember defines no way of setting the `this` in promise callbacks, and there is no need for that, because two perfectly legal, widely adopted methods exist to solve that problem. Pick one of them.

Comment: I'm just pushing forward normal behavior of opting for the easiest way of using bind(this) or saving the current scope in a variable, looking for a deep understanding of how js lexical scope works around functions. I know those techniques you mention, I'm just curious if I can achieved it in different ways.